# Stop OWIN SignalR services on Server

Tags: asp.net, signalr, owin

The [MSDN tutorial on SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) shows how to start the SignalR services via OWIN in an ASP.NET application.

However I could not find any example that shows how to stop SignalR services on the server when not required.

For example if SignalR is used for real-time stock price updates, stop the services when markets are closed for trading.

Comment: Any guidance is appreciated.